# Only want one answer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

How do I make fold{l,r} terminate when I only want one answer?

Suppose I have a list of booleans b1,b2,b3,... and I want to OR all of them together. How do I get fold to stop on the first true value?

Comment: Even shorter than jozefg's answer: try `or $ repeat True` in GHCi!

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's just because `or = foldr (||) False`, as defined in the Prelude. GHC actually defines it recursively for some reason—based on the context that's probably to enable a special or/build optimization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It already does! As an example let's make a list

```
foo :: [Bool]
foo = [False, False, False, True] ++ repeat False
```

where `repeat` just makes an infinite list, and if we load this into GHCi

```
*Main> foldr (||) False foo
  True
```

"But, but how?" you might wonder, well Haskell is lazy and so is `foldr`. If you look at the implementation, you'll notice that it creates something like this

```
 foldr f a [b, c, d, e ... z] == (b `f` (c `f` (... (z `f` a)..)))
```

Notice that when you evaluate it, if `f` doesn't need that right side, it won't be evaluated and we could ignore the whole rest of the list, even if it's infinite. This is possible in a lazy language like Haskell because we only evaluate things when they're needed.

In the case of `||` since it's defined as

```
True  || _ = True
False || a = a
```

when the left side is true, we stop evaluating the list. Short circuiting for free!

Note, `foldl` doesn't share this nice property since it touches all elements of the list. This leads to a nice rule of thumb, if you want short circuiting/nonstrictness, `foldr` is usually the right choice, otherwise `foldl'` is probably faster.